# BASH find -name (read variable)

Tags: bash, variables, find

I'm new to bash and have encountered a problem i can't solve. The issue is i need to use find -name with a name defined as a variable. Part of the script:

```
read MYNAME
find -name $MYNAME
```

But when i run the script, type in '*sh' for read, there are 0 results.
However, if i type directly in the terminal:

```
find -name '*sh'
```

it's working fine.

I also tried

```
read MYNAME
find -name \'$MYNAME\'
```

with typing *sh for read and no success.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It would help if you gave examples of files which you expect to match (i.e. define "working fine"), and also specify whether you are executing or `source`-ing the script.  By the way, it's conventional to use lowercase for non-constant variables, not uppercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably

```
read MYNAME
find -name "$MYNAME"
```

is the version you are looking for. Without the double quotes `"` the shell will expand `*` in your `*sh` example prior to running `find` that's why your first attempt didn't work

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
find -name "$MYNAME"
```

since this prevents `$MYNAME` from being subject to bash's pathname expansion (a.k.a. "globbing"), resulting in `*sh` being passed intact to `find`.  One key difference is that globbing will not match hidden files such as `.ssh`, whereas `find -name "*sh"` will.  However since you don't define the expected behaviour you are seeking, it's hard to say what you need for sure.